# How to set an environment variable on OSX Yosemite?

Tags: macos, environment-variables

I am trying to set a global/system variable in my computer, I am using Yosemite.

I opened my ~/.profile (that is the default profile file configuration) , and I added this

```
setenv var.Property someValue
```

but it didnt work,

Neither this way

```
export var.Property = someValue
```

everytime I do echo $var.Property I get as result "Property" I think the "." may be interfering with this. I do need to have it this format, but unfortunately, is not working.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: What if you remove the spaces either side of `=` and do `export var.Property=something` and also use `echo ${var.Property}`?

Comment: it has the same result

Comment: I presume you actually put that in `~/.profile` and not `~/.profiles`?

Comment: yes, sorry, it is on the "profile" file

Answer (score 0):

You will get a different environment based on if you start via command line vs double clicking ... if you start with the command line you should get whatever is in `env` and if you start by clicking it then you will get whatever is in launchtl's env... so for that to change you use

```
launchctl setenv DOG cat
```

Edit:

it seems as though you can't have an env var with a key that has a period in it... this works fine in csh:

```
setenv var.Property someValue
```

Comment: Im starting a tomcat that brings a property file for my java app, cant modify that file, but I should set those values somewhere, so, I thought enviroment variables should work... any idea why doesnt work if I use the dot?

Comment: well my guess is that bash won't let you, you might be able to set them that way with `setenv` library call, i.e., from a C program... or just don't do that

Comment: @jpganz18 actually it looks like you might be able to set them in csh and tcsh... http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/is-it-possible-to-set-an-environment-variable-name-containing-a-period-in-bash-724256/